# Can I use the PHP extension built on other environment or even other PHP version?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to install some extension in Linux env, but somehow "PECL install" command doesn't work in current production env. It works in my local environment.

Question: Can I upload the .so file installed in local environment and use it directly in the production env? Is there any potential compatibility issue?

Do I need to use exact same PHP version as prod env? What if my local php is 7.4 and php in Prod is 8.0?

Comment: What is your production environment?

Comment: Versions should be both the same. In PHP 8 there are some decrepations,

Comment: They don't need to be the same exact version but they do need to be the same minor version, so extensions compiled for 7.4 won't work with 8.0. Also note some extensions may have external dependencies, so you can't always assume just copying the module alone will work. Your best best is to address the error you're getting so you can compile locally. That said, what "doesn't work?" What error are you getting?